# Android control widget layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm trying to make a widget which is a togglebutton like the ones in the android control widget (the quicksettings for wlan, bluetooth etc.).

[Here's how it looks](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/widgets.html) (@Control Widgets)

Does anyone know if this layout is contained in the android sdk or if not how I can make a layout just like that one?

I've already tried some things but I don't know how do to the stroke at the bottom.

Comment: Work with gimp or photoshop create your own picture for unpressed and one for pressed. Load/set pressed image when widget is pressed and load picture/image unpressed when widget is clicked again? There you got your toggle button.. Would be my first idea on how to get that run..

Comment: thought so, too, but I don't think that's the best way to achieve that.
I'm pretty sure they did that using drawables.

Comment: Please tell me how to define widget to be control widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding to your issue I searched a little bit deeper.

See: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

These are the classes which you can use with an appwidget to implement in your layout there is no such thing like a toggle button, but an imagebutton which I think us exactly what Google is using for the "toggle buttons". Take a closer look on the imagebutton : 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

Then you will find out it's exactly what you are looking for.

```
    By default, an ImageButton looks like a regularButton, with the standard button background that changes color during different button states. The image on the surface of the button is defined either by the android:src attribute in the XML element or by thesetImageResource(int) method.
```

I can't imagine that such a complex layout is possible just using clean xml...

Hope it helps now!

Comment: Ty for your effort. I know the ImageButton control but I was hoping for a more elegant solution. But well seems like there'd be no other way than using an image.

Comment: @Stefan Not really. Please mark as accepted answere. But again such "complex" layout with just plaine xml seems not possible gor me. Please mark as accepted